# How can groups make more progress in moving public discourse past denial of anthropogenic climate change?

Tags: united-states, climate-change

Many organized groups assert that anthropogenic climate change is one of the most pressing issues facing the USA. Others deny it exists.  Have any responses to their denial of this issue proven to be effective in changing people's minds?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad.  "Best ways" is way too open-ended.  It's also opinion-based and possibly off-topic.  If you'd like to ask how *politicians* can do so, or ask how the public can influence their politicians, or what specific policies could help, or so on, that'd be a reasonable question.

Comment: @Bobson I concur. It's hard to see how you could generate a constructive answer out of this. Maybe if someone has a specific relevant study about effective ways, but even then, that wouldn't necessarily mean 'best' unless we define the term a bit better.

Comment: @user1873 This edit seems to be _huge_ change in intent. The question is better now (though "alarmism" might be unecessarily connotation laden), but it wasn't what was asked.

Comment: @Avi, the change isn't that big. The OP wanted to know what the most effective way organizations could spread alarmism about climate change. Polls show that they **haven't been** that effective to date. So, it answers their question in a round about way, (I.e. stop doing what you are currently doing, it isn't working.) Alarmism isn't any worse than denialism, neither you or Bobson seemed to mention denialism as an issue.

Comment: @user1873, Regardless of whether alarm and denial are equally undesirable, they are different conditions and the original question only addressed denial. Currently denial is not part of the question, and this changes it substantially.

Comment: It looks like the fundamental question that you're tying to ask is an opinion based question.  We generally don't accept those kinds of questions at Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @SamIam, thank you for commenting. While the question does ask for opinions, it regards political strategy and a good answer would be supported by references to accounts of preceding political struggles, current polls, and other documents. So, like many political questions, it ultimately hinges on opinion, but this can be informed opinion. Is this allowed? The question could be rephrased along the lines of: "Which political strategies are most likely to be effective responses to denial of anthropogenic climate change?"

Comment: @Grant Some people around here seem to like that sort of re-wording, but I personally think that doing that just obfuscates the problem.

Comment: @SamIam, thanks again. I am new here, so I am open to suggestions. As I glance at the questions to my right I count six asking for opinions and four requesting only facts. Might the present question be acceptable in this context?

Comment: An effective response hasn't been found yet.

Comment: Also, gotta enjoy the irony of user1873's attempted edit.

Comment: Yes, @DA., if *only* someone would find the effective response, then nothing else would be necessary. Reminds me of the folks who claim that communism has failed - repeatedly - only because it hasn't truly been tried yet.

Comment: @user438 yep. If only. Maybe someday.

Comment: @Grant - I made an edit to try and make it less opinion-based and less "list question"-ish (and therefore less likely to be closed).  Please let me know if I stayed close enough to your intent.

Comment: @Bobson I hate that we have to add the term "anthropogenic". I get why you did it, but it's really part of the entire problem with the whole 'debate'. One side tries to nitpick the definitions and claim there is strong evidence separating GW and AGW. The other side, the scientists, point out that they are inseparable issues.

Comment: Could you reword your question such to avoid triple negation etc? I have no hell idea what's your actual question, as it stays.

Comment: @Bobson, the current wording seems good to me.

Comment: Yep, @DA. All we need to do is crack another 100 million or so eggs - but we'll make that omelet come hell or high water! (Never mind that it'll be full of grit and completely inedible...)

Comment: @user438 high water is definitely coming. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not very effective. A [gallup poll in 2014](http://www.gallup.com/poll/167843/climate-change-not-top-worry.aspx) listed it second from the bottom only ahead of **race relations** when ranking a list of 15 problems facing the USA.

> WASHINGTON, D.C. -- Twenty-eight U.S. senators held an all-night "talkathon" Monday to call attention to climate change, an issue that only 24% of Americans say they worry about a great deal. This puts climate change, along with the quality of the environment, near the bottom of a list of 15 issues Americans rated in Gallup's March 6-9 survey. The economy, federal spending, and healthcare dominate Americans' worries.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

> What are effective responses to denial of this issue?

As [the US still leads the world in global warming denial](http://ecowatch.com/2014/07/22/americans-lead-world-climate-denial/), I think the answer to this question is simply "no one has figured out what an effective response to climate denial is as of yet".

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear the reason for maintaining the position of denial is to avoid the anticipated costs that will come with universal acceptance. Denial is being used as a wallet shield. Nobody wants to fund the war on climate change when still paying for all the other unwinable wars. So stop focusing the evidence supporting climate change and begin working on the economic reasons denial is an attractive position to hold. The science debate has been taken about as far as it will go for the moment. Focus discussions on economically attractive solutions.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score -2):

By using the correct terminology, first of all. No one denies "climate change"; the climate is of course always changing. The question is whether it is being changed primarily by human agency or by natural causes.

Furthermore, calling it "denial" is also simply an attempt to poison the well. Those who argue against it aren't in "denial" but are skeptical about it and are demanding a certain standard of evidence.

Comment: I like the gist of this answer, but I quibble with the specifics.  There *are* people who deny that the climate is changing at all, and both sides often use the phrase "climate change" to specifically refer to "human-generated climate change".  Likewise, there are people who flat out deny the evidence [while calling themselves skeptics](http://arstechnica.com/staff/2014/12/skeptics-deniers-and-contrarians-the-climate-science-label-game/), so it would be only proper to call them deniers.

Comment: @Bobson: from that article: "There's no shortage of denial when it comes to climate change—the public proclamations of Senator James Inhofe (R-Okla.), which the letter cites, are classic examples." The letter, though, cites only this statement from Inhofe: "global warming is 'the greatest hoax ever perpetrated on the American people.'" That is *not* a denial of climate change, but of the specific claim of global warming. It is this kind of fudging of the facts, and readiness to declare any contrary opinions heretical, that makes people see this less as science and more as a neo-Inquisition.

Comment: Like I said: `both sides often use the phrase "climate change" to specifically refer to "human-generated climate change".`  It's shorthand, although (as you point out) it's not technically accurate.  [The recent Senate vote](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-fix/wp/2015/01/21/jim-inhofe-flips-the-script-on-democratic-climate-change-is-a-hoax-vote/) is a great example.  Even Inhofe voted to say that the climate does change, after making a speech saying that it's "the role of humans" that is a hoax.

Comment: Given the recently edited question, this answer is now irrelevant.

Comment: Arguing that the issue is one of nitpicking definitions isn't a proven solution. It's been attempted, and hasn't worked.

Comment: Also 'denial' is a perfectly valid word for what this is. The 'certain standard of evidence' doesn't exist, as they are actively in denial. When 95+% of the scientific community agrees, that's just plain denial.

Comment: @DA.: the "certain standard of evidence" might be, you know, citing evidence rather than "95+% of the scientific community," which is nothing more than an appeal to authority, and one which has been repeatedly contradicted anyway. That "certain standard of evidence" might also include things such as not falsifying data and then falsely claiming "exoneration" by various bodies who have done no such thing. And so forth.

Comment: @user438 you are proving the point. Claiming that science is 'merely appealing to authority' sums it up well.

Comment: @user438 - I don't ask my doctor to provide evidence of whatever he's diagnosing or a detailed explanation of how the body systems interact to produce the symptoms I'm seeing - I just confirm that his diagnosis does describe what I see.  Likewise, I don't ask the mechanic to give me a guided tour to the car repairs he's making, or my manager to give me a blow-by-blow description of all the priorities he's juggling, or a biochemist to describe drug interactions.  I take their words that they've evaluated the evidence and reached an informed conclusion.  Why should climate science be different?

Comment: @user438 - I try to stay apolitical on this stack, and approach things neutrally even when I disagree.  But that only holds while other people remain rational.  I can't abide irrationality.  Would you consider [this map](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2015/01/17/hottest-year/06a6623dd8c0255a12756a0c98c77520d63f8ee5/temp_light-720.png) evidence?  Recorded temperatures?  Melting polar ice?  Are you qualified to tell me whether any of those *actually* prove anything?  I'm certainly not, but the scientists who are say they do.

Comment: @Bobson, I'll tell you a personal experience of mine on the subject. A close relative of mine is a prominent science writer, and indeed in the '70s he was one of the first to write about global warming. Well, some years ago I asked him how to evaluate the various claims on the subject. His answer? Not even appealing to the 95%, but "Global warming is a fact *because I wrote about it*!" Now, this is someone whose entire 30+-year career was spent in studying science and writing about it. If that's his strongest argument for the reality of the theory, then that speaks rather poorly for it.

Comment: "I'll tell you a personal experience of mine on the subject" = but that's not science. That's a personal anecdote. Fun for arguing, but not for actually coming to proper conclusions based no proper data and analysis.

Comment: @DA.: "no proper data" - what a Freudian slip!

Comment: Anti-Science 'Skeptics' Are Not Skeptics: http://www.realclearscience.com/blog/2015/02/anti-science_skeptics_are_not_skeptics_they_are_incredibly_willing_to_believe_bs.html

Comment: @Grant: when you have a field - and quite a few practitioners thereof - rife with fraud and overblown claims, "tricks" to "hide the decline," and a complete unwillingness to even acknowledge criticism, instead damning it as "denialism" and so forth - why, then, it is indeed correct to be skeptical of such claims. It is simply an abuse of language to describe that as being "anti-science."

Comment: @user438: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz8Ve6KE-Us